# Why is better to wrap (and multiple) code for sake of Law of Demeter?

Tags: php, law-of-demeter

```
class Point
{
    private $x, $y;

    public __construction ($x, $y)
    {
        $this->x = $x;
        $this->y = $y;
    }

    public function getX()
    {
        return $this->x;
    }

    public function getY()
    {
        return $this->y;
    }
}
```

first I would write this:

```
class Item
{
    private $point; // Point

    public __construction()
    {
        $this->point = new Point(0,0);
    }

    public function getPoint()
    {
        return $this->point;
    }
}
```

and then:

```
$p = new Item();
$p->getPoint()->getX();
```

but they say it violates that law. After refactoring:

```
class Item
{
    private $point; // Point

    public __construction()
    {
        $this->point = new Point(0,0);
    }

    public function getPointX()
    {
        return $this->point->getX();
    }

    public function getPointY()
    {
        return $this->point->getY();
    }
}
```

and then:

```
$p = new Item();
$p->getPointX();
```

this time `getPointX()` and `getPointY()` is just a redundant "transmission" method. I understand that ig `Point` has 1000 other methods, it would be unsafe to just return this all object as `return $this->point`. But this time all properties are covered.

Answer (score 2):

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)

Because your `$p` requires more information about `Point` than it needs:

> In particular, an object should avoid invoking methods of a member object returned by another method

Comment: @JohnSmith Read Advantages/Disadvantages of same resource.